# Removal of house numbers on stucco!

Tags: stucco

I have house numbers on my stucco there are no screws. They seem to be glued on in someway. How can I remove them? I want to put new floating more modern numbers on. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: can you add a picture?

Answer (score 4):

Probably construction adhesive. The main problem is that this doesn't come off cleanly. On stucco, this is likely to turn into gouging out the letters, glue, and the stucco underneath, then repairing the stucco. Figure out if this is acceptable now.

You can use a hairdryer to heat up the area to soften the glue. There might be screws underneath, used for creating a good surface to adhere to.

Answer (score 2):

Second option is to leave the old numbers there, box over them and put your fancy new numbers on the front.

You could use the same colour for the numbers as the stucco, and a contrasting colour for your box.  Or face the front of the box with frosted glass/perspex and backlight it with LEDs.

---

You could try adding more stucco over the existing numbers, but that's probably going to leave an unsightly lump so framing would be neater.

---

The really lazy solution is to paint the old numbers the same colour as the stucco, and then ignore them.

Good luck !